# Como converter CSV para XLSX com python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Como eu faço para converter um arquivo `.csv` gerado pelo python para `.xlsx`?

Estou com dois problemas:

- Um deles é que eu não consegui entender como fazer esta conversão
- O segundo é que mesmo passando o comando

  ```
  crawl <nome> -o <nome>.csv -s CSV_DELIMITER=";"
  ```

  no arquivo scrapy, na hora que eu abro o arquivo gerado direto pelo Excel, o mesmo não formata as colunas, deixando separado por vírgulas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import *
from Aranhas.items import ImprensaNacional
import csv
from Aranhas.settings import *
from Aranhas.pipelines import *

class imprensa_Nacional(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imprensa_Nacional'
    start_urls = ['http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/leiturajornal?data=11-09-2018&secao=dou3']

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': [
            'Titulo', 'Tipo', 'Pregao', 'UASG', 'DOU', 'DataPublicacao', 'EdicaoDou',
            'SecaoDou','Pagina', 'Orgao','Pregoeiro', 'Url', 'Descricao'
        ],
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        url_base = 'http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/'
        script = response.xpath('//*[@class="span8 hierarchy-wrapper"]//*[contains(text(),"AVISO DE LICITA")]')
        for urls in script:
            links = urls.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            link_completo = url_base + str(links)
            yield Request(url=link_completo, callback=self.parseAviso)

    def parseAviso(self, response):
        conteudo = response.xpath('//*[@class="journal-content-article"]')
        for info in conteudo:
            titulo = info.xpath('.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            pregao = info.xpath(u'.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"N\xba")]').extract_first().split()[3].strip()
            uasg = info.xpath(u'.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"N\xba")]').extract_first().split()[6].strip()
            tipo = info.xpath('.//*[@class="identifica"]/text()[contains(.,"AVISO")]').extract_first().strip()
            pregoeiro = info.xpath('.//*[@class="assina"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            descricao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="dou-paragraph"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            dou = info.xpath('.//*[@class="dou-paragraph"]/text()[contains(.,"(")]').extract_first().strip()
            orgao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="orgao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            data_publicacao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="publicado-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            edicao_dou = info.xpath('.//*[@class="edicao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            secao = info.xpath('.//*[@class="secao-dou"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            pagina = info.xpath('.//*[@class="secao-dou-data"]/text()').extract_first().strip()

            item = ImprensaNacional()
            item.set_all()

            item['Titulo'] = titulo.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Tipo'] = tipo.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Pregao'] = pregao.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['UASG'] = uasg.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['DOU'] = dou.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['DataPublicacao'] = data_publicacao.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['EdicaoDou'] = edicao_dou.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['SecaoDou'] = secao.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Pagina'] = pagina.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Orgao'] = orgao.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Pregoeiro'] = pregoeiro.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Url'] = response.url.encode('iso-8859-1')
            item['Descricao'] = descricao.encode('iso-8859-1')

            yield item
```

Answer (score 2):

Outro legal também (além do Pandas) é o [rows](https://github.com/turicas/rows) (instalável com pip install rows, mas depois vai pedir a instalação manual de alguns outros pacotes, também com pip, par funcionar).

É uma biblioteca em Python para tratamento de tabelas, que além de facilitar a leitura e processamento de vários formatos de arquivo e dados em páginas na Web, disponibiliza, uma vez instalado, o comando `rows` no terminal, que pode fazer a conversão deseada de forma tão simples quanto digitar `rows convert arquivo.csv arquivo.xlsx`.

Answer (score 1):

Veja pandas, onde você pode ler um csv e usar a função ExcelWriter e to_excel para fazer as escritas.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Outro pacote que pode te ajudar é o Openpyxl:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/